# How to transfer data to Ubuntu-Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

If you want to transfer data (for example pictures) from your Ubuntu-Touch device, you have to type this in the terminal:

"adb **pull** /home/phablet/Pictures/"

This works for all kinds of data to transfer it to the pc.
But how can I transfer data from my pc to the Ubuntu-Touch device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the related `push` command:

```
adb push /local/filename /home/phablet/wherever
```

Alternatively, if you install `openssh-server` on the phone, you can copy files back and forward using `scp` or `sftp`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I just had to add these punctuiation marks: **adb push '/local/filename' '/home/phablet/wherever'** for it to work.

Comment: The quotation marks should only be necessary if the file names contain spaces (the same as for other command line tools).  I didn't include them above, since my example paths didn't contain any special characters.